# How do I make a dynamic ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I would like to use a function to generate a plain object that will be exported from an ES6 module (using Babel to transpile my code before running in Node)

---

The following module is what I would like to make...

`module_a`

```js
function generatePlainObject(param1, param2, param3) {
    return {
        newProp1: param1,
        newProp2: param2,
        newProp3: param3,
    };
}

export generatePlainObject(1, 2, 3);
```

...so I can use `import { newProp1, newProp2, newProp3 } from 'module_a'` in another module, and access the properties easily.

But this throws an error (`unexpected token`) specifically.

I've tried using a spread operator (`...`), and using `Object.assign({}, funcResults)` and storing that in a `const` before exporting but they all pop up errors.

---

Is this even possible? Am I misunderstanding what kind of objects I can make to export? Do I have to explicitly type out the plain object and include its properties?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which JavaScript environment are you using and does it support `export`?

Comment: ES6 import and export are static and they are supposed to be statically analyzed. Is there something that prevents you from exporting this object as default export? You can do dynamic exports with CJS module.

Comment: `export {a,  b, c};` is not an object expression, it is a list of names to export, so you can't replace it with an arbitrary expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the spec, ES6 modules must be *statically analyzable*. That means they cannot be generated at runtime. This allows for a lot of nice optimizations like [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

If you really want to do this, you can use CommonJS modules like this...

```
module.exports = generatePlainObject(1, 2, 3);
```

And import like this...

```
import { newProp1, newProp2 } from './otherFile';
```

---

The other option is to export as default and then import the entire object like this...

```
export default generatePlainObject(1, 2, 3);
```

And import like this...

```
import theWholeObj from './otherFile';
console.log(theWholeObj.newProp1);
```

Both of these methods are **not** *statically analyzable* and therefore make tree shaking impossible. This means that anytime you import `newProp1`, you will also be importing `newProp2` and `newProp3` regardless whether you use them or not.